# Questions on scalability of getting most recent posts from users someone is following: two different implementations

Tags: mysql, design-patterns, database-design, relational-database, innodb

I have two different implementations for retrieving polls from the users someone is following and I want to know which one lends itself to a database that will be more scalable. First I'll show you the tables, and then the two implementations.

poll table

```
CREATE TABLE `poll` (
`id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`creator_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`question` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`num_of_responses` int(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`num_of_answers` enum('2','3','4','5') NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `creator_id` (`creator_id`),
KEY `date_created` (`date_created`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

.

repoll table -necessary for both implementations

```
CREATE TABLE `repoll` (
`repoller_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`poll_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
KEY `repoller_id` (`repoller_id`),
KEY `poll_id` (`poll_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

.

following table

```
CREATE TABLE `following` (
`follower` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`followee` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
KEY `follower` (`follower`),
KEY `followee` (`followee`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

.

user_feed table -necessary only for second implementation

```
CREATE TABLE `user_feed` (
`user_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`poll_id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`repoller_id` int(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
KEY `date_created` (`date_created`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

.

First implementation: Doesn't require the user_feed table, but the query seems much more computationally expensive than the query in implementation two.

```
SELECT P.id, P.creator_id, P.date_created
FROM
following f JOIN
(
    SELECT id, creator_id, date_created
    FROM poll
    UNION ALL
    SELECT poll_id, repoller_id, date_created
    FROM repoll
) AS P(id, creator_id, date_created)
ON f.followee=P.creator_id
AND f.follower=23
ORDER BY P.date_created DESC
LIMIT 120;
```

Second implementation: Requires the user_feed table and the repoll table. I add a record to the user_feed table every time someone posts/repolls something. The record is added for each one of the poster's followers. I only keep, say, 120 records for any particular user in the user_feed table. If a post is made and a user already has 120 records in the user_feed table, the oldest record for that user is removed and added to the repoll table; and the new one takes its place. If a user requests more records than there are present in the user_feed table for them, then the first implementation is used to retrieve the excess.

```
SELECT uf.poll_id, p.creator_id, uf.repoller_id, uf.date_created
FROM
user_feed uf JOIN poll p
ON uf.poll_id=p.id
AND uf.user_id=23
ORDER BY date_created DESC;
```

Comment: `OR` id deadly on performance.  `IN ( SELECT ... )` is deadly on performance.  And note that you needs parens around `SELECT`.  Rewrite `IN` as a `JOIN`; then we can discuss scalability further.  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: As Rick James noted, the MySQL optimizer can generate some horrendous plans with OR conditions. We generally get much better performance out of queries using join operations. But that all really depends on available indexes, and whether the query can make effective use of the index, or whether MySQL can't use an index because a column is wrapped in a function. From a performance scalability standpoint, I'm not really liking either of those two options. But at first blush, it looks like the second query has a better shot at getting reasonable access plan, with suitable indexes available.

Comment: Some additional notes... UNION operation requires a Using filesort operation to identify and remove duplicates. The UNION ALL set operator doesn't perform that operation. For performance, use UNION ALL if identifying and removing duplicates is not required. With both, the number of columns and the datatypes of the columns of the sets being combined need to match. And don't enclose identifiers in single quotes. Single quotes enclose string literals. And inline views get converted into derived tables, which can incur a performance penalty with large sets.

Comment: @RickJames Ok, completely upgraded the queries. Ready to start talking about scalability of the implementations?

Answer (score 0):

Unwinding that original query, it looks like the query is looking for:

- polls created by 23
- repolls created by 23
- polls created by someone followed by 23
- repolls created by someone followed by 23

Assuming that there's a restriction on rows in `following` such that 23 cannot be follower of himself (i.e. no rows allowed where follower=followee)

And also assuming that a user cannot repoll the same poll at the same exact time, that is, (poll_id, creator_id, created_on) tuple is UNIQUE in repoll

(and probably some other conditions I've not identified yet...)

It looks like four distinct sets:

1) polls created by 23

```
 SELECT p.id
      , p.creator_id
      , p.created_on
      , NULL AS repoller_id
   FROM poll p
  WHERE p.creator_id = 23
  ORDER BY p.created_on DESC LIMIT 80
```

2) repolls by 23

```
 SELECT p.id
      , p.creator_id
      , r.created_on
      , r.repoller_id
   FROM poll p
   JOIN repoll r
     ON r.poll_id = p.id
  WHERE r.repoller_id = 23
  ORDER BY r.created_on DESC LIMIT 80
```

3) polls created by someone followed by 23

```
 SELECT p.id
      , p.creator_id
      , p.created_on
      , NULL AS repoller_id
   FROM poll p
   JOIN following f
     ON f.followee = p.creator_id
    AND f.follower = 23
    AND f.follower <> f.followee  -- only needed if we don't disallow 23 to follow 23
  ORDER BY p.created_on DESC LIMIT 80
```

4) repolls created by someone followed by 23

```
 SELECT p.id
      , r.creator_id
      , r.created_on
      , r.repoller_id
   FROM poll p
   JOIN repoll r
     ON r.poll_id = p.id
   JOIN following f
     ON f.followee = r.repoller_id
    AND f.follower = 23
    AND f.follower <> f.followee   -- only needed if we don't disallow 23 to follow 23
  ORDER BY r.created_on DESC LIMIT 80
```

If there's some possibility of duplicates that need to be eliminated (for example because we don't have appropriate UNIQUE constraints on the tables) we can add GROUP BY clause to the queries required.

We can tune each of these individual queries, making sure appropriate indexes are available and being used, using EXPLAIN.

Then we can combine the queries with UNION ALL set operators. My preference is to not reuse any table aliases in a query, even if its unambiguous to MySQL, it makes the statement easier to read, and in particular, makes the EXPLAIN easier to decipher when every table reference has a unique alias.

Since the original query orders by created_on in descending order, and specifies a limit of 80 rows returned, we can apply that same ordering and limit on each individual subquery. When we get to the order by on the whole set, we'll have at most 320 (=4x80 rows.) To make the result more deterministic, we'll include a second expression in the order by clauses.

```
(
  SELECT p1.id
       , p1.creator_id
       , p1.created_on
       , NULL AS repoller_id
    FROM poll p1
   WHERE p1.creator_id = 23         -- query parameter
   ORDER BY p1.created_on DESC, p1.id DESC LIMIT 80
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT p2.id
       , p2.creator_id
       , r2.created_on
       , r2.repoller_id
    FROM poll p2
    JOIN repoll r2
      ON r2.poll_id = p2.id
   WHERE r2.repoller_id = 23         -- query parameter
   ORDER BY r2.created_on DESC, r2.poll_id DESC LIMIT 80
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT p3.id
       , p3.creator_id
       , p3.created_on
       , NULL AS repoller_id
    FROM poll p3
    JOIN following f3
      ON f3.followee = p3.creator_id
     AND f3.follower = 23            -- query parameter
     AND f3.follower <> f3.followee  -- only needed if we allow 23 to follow 23
   ORDER BY p3.created_on DESC, p3.id DESC LIMIT 80
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT p4.id
       , p4.creator_id
       , r4.created_on
       , r4.repoller_id
    FROM poll p4
    JOIN repoll r4
      ON r4.poll_id = p4.id
    JOIN following f4
      ON f4.followee = r4.repoller_id
     AND f4.follower = 23            -- query parameter
     AND f4.follower <> f4.followee  -- only needed if we allow 23 to follow 23
   ORDER BY r4.created_on DESC, r4.poll_id DESC LIMIT 80
)
ORDER BY created_on DESC, id DESC LIMIT 80
```

Even though the SQL text in this query is longer than either of the two options you posted, I would expect we'd have a much better shot at predictable performance, given suitable indexes.

In place of the indexes on the singleton column `creator_id`

```
CREATE INDEX poll_IX1 ON poll (creator_id, created_on, id) ; 
CREATE INDEX repoll_IX1 ON repoll (creator_id, created_on, id)
```

And on the `following` table, make a unique constraint, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE `following` ADD PRIMARY KEY (follower, followee)
```

And not for this query, but for other queries that are likely used in the system...

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX following_UX1 ON following (followee_id, follower_id)
```

And drop the (now redundant) indexes on the singleton columns of the `following` table.

Also consider adding appropriate foreign key constraints.

Comment: As an alternative, if we have rows in the \`following\` table for every creator_id such that creator_id follows himself, and every repoller_id also  follows himself, we could eliminate queries 1 and 2, and use just queries 3 and 4, removing the  follower <> followee restriction.

Comment: Jesus Christ. This... this is just amazing. You must be superman or smn. Just read through it now, and it's going to take me a while to decipher it -newb. But thank you... a lot. I'm going to get back to you after I've processed it all; especially if I have any questions

Comment: We'd really need to look at the EXPLAIN, and at the expected cardinality (number of rows, number of distinct values in the columns, data distribution.) The MySQL optimizer sometimes comes up with horrendous plans for queries including OR conditions. (Not every OR condition, but with conditions that influence index choices and join paths.) One of the biggest issues with this is the number of rows that need to be returned. If we can get the ORDER BY satisfied using an index, avoiding potentially expensive "Using filesort" operations on large sets.

Comment: You are on the right track, evaluating potential approaches, and the examining the performance characteristics. There's no guarantee that the pattern I suggest in my answer is going to be "faster" than the options you already outlined. It's just one possible way to look at the problem, with potential for tuning each individual query. (Breaking an important OR condition into a UNION of two queries is a familiar pattern  in tuning MySQL queries for predictable performance.)

Comment: NOTE: The table definitions in the original question were edited to change the name of the \`created_on\` column to \`date_created\`. The example queries in this answer were written based on the column names in the table definitions at the time this answer was posted.

Comment: @khakis: there is no "accept an edit" action available to me. i received notification that an edit had been proposed, and that the proposed edit had been rejected. (not by me, by someone else). the stackoverflow review queues are plenty full, there's no need to add unnecessary edits to that queue.

Comment: got it. so, it seems like an approach with one server running mysql and php servicing thousands of users using the above query wouldn't hold up very long. is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Implementation 1 can be improved thus:

```
SELECT  P.id, P.creator_id, P.date_created
    FROM  following f
    JOIN (
          ( SELECT  id, creator_id, date_created
                FROM  poll
                ORDER BY  date_created DESC
                LIMIT  120
          ) UNION  ALL 
          (  SELECT  poll_id, repoller_id, date_created
                FROM  repoll
                ORDER BY  date_created DESC
                LIMIT  120
          )
         ) AS P   ON f.followee=P.creator_id
      AND  f.follower=23
    ORDER BY  P.date_created DESC
    LIMIT  120;

poll and repoll need:  INDEX(creator_id, date_created)
```

Explanation:  In *most* situations, the seemingly redundant `ORDER BY .. LIMIT ..` clause is actually an optimization.  In the `SELECTs` in the `UNION` it minimizes the number of rows to store in the temp table that `UNION` will create.  The temp table will have no more than 2*120 rows; this is important if the tables have millions of rows.  The outer query also needs the clauses in order to shuffle the sublists together and whittle the result down to just the 120 that are desired.

Improve indexes and allow for "covering indexes":

```
CREATE TABLE `following` (
  `follower` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `followee` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`follower`, followee),
  INDEX      (`followee`, follower)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Explanation:  I assume that the *combination* of `follower` and `followee` is 'unique', hence can be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  The performance benefit of doing things this way is that all the followees for a given follower are found in adjacent rows, and vice versa.  What you originally had is significantly slower because it had to first look in the index, then read into the data in order to get both fields.  What I give you is both "covering" and "clustered"

Shouldn't your second flavor have a `LIMIT`?

`uf` needs `INDEX(user_id, date_created)`

As for your original question of 'which', ... I don't see that the second query does the right thing.

Comment: thanks for your response. a couple of things: one, i don't think i can make the follower column in the following table the primary key; being that a single user can follow many others, so the column wouldn't contain unique values - an index perhaps? two, there is no limit for the user feed table because i limited the number of records that the table would contain for any particular user to 120. that way a select statement would only be able to retrieve at most 120 records when retrieving the most recent polls/repolls from a user's feed.

Comment: check out the preface before the second implementation. it's explained there. on an optimization note, i thoght that it might be easier for whatever is doing the work in mysql to order the poll/repolls by date once, after it did the union all; instead of ordering them both before the union and then again afterwards. but i suppose because both the poll select and the repoll select are limited to 120 records, the ordering after the union wouldn't be very costly on the cpu. other than the pre-ordering, it is the same as my query

Comment: is that index you suggested for the user_feed table two separate indexes or one composite index?

Comment: See two new paragraphs of "Explanation".  See also [my cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).